# Unsupported target type: boolean, using puppeteer waitFor function

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I am trying to do something like this below

```
const url = await page.url();
await page.waitFor(url === 'localhost:3000/blogs');
```

I have also tried

```
await page.waitFor(url).toEqual('localhost:3000/blogs');
```

And also tried all these scenarios with the `waitForFunction` method and could not get any to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [waitFor](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) function accepts a selector, function or timeout. If you want to see if url is equal to something, then write a function for it. Pass the url as an argument so you can read it within the browser context.

```
const url = await page.url();
await page.waitFor((url)=> url === 'http://localhost:3000/blogs', url); // <-- use a function
```

Also you can use browsers built in code to wait for url to match.

```
await page.waitFor(()=> location.href === 'http://localhost:3000/blogs');
```

Note, since you are using `===` to match a string, make sure to include `http://` since `location.href` will output the url with the protocol.

If you want to use jest, then you can use `expect` and wrap it in a `it` block.

```
it('should contain specific url', async () => {
    const url = await page.url();
    expect(url).toContain('localhost:3000/blogs');
});
```

Here is a document for [jest and puppeteer together](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html).

Comment: I'm getting `url` is not defined. I think this has to do with the async, await part. And yes I know about doing the jest part! I just wanted to see if it was possible to do it in the `waitFor`

Comment: That fixed that problem but now the test times out. It is hanging for some reason. I tried to console log the url inside the waitFor function and couldnt get a value.

Comment: waitFor will run the code inside browser context, you cannot console log that without an event listener also make sure to use proper url with http etc like I used with second example.